# Is it there any way to prevent alt+f4 shutdown in windows

Tags: windows, keyboard, shutdown

I face the problem of my coworker often shutdowns by simply pressing <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f4</kbd> often he shut downs it. Is it there any way to stop this kind of activities in order to prevent accidental shutdown?

Answer (score 1):

why cant you disable the shut down by changing the keys bindings for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f4</kbd> key?

Navigate to registry editor by typing regedit `

Navigate to the following registry location

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER --> SOFTWARE --> MICROSOFT --> WINDOWS –> POLICIES
>   –> EXPLORER

Then on the right side of Registry Editor, Right Click your mouse to open a list.

Now go to NEW –> Dwood Value.

Name this value as **“NoClose“**

After creating click on it and give Value Data **1**

now reboot your pc ,next time cant shutdown your pc

hope it helps

Comment: Out of date path. Also, just copy and paste the actual path with \ and everything. Now someone can just paste that into regedit instead of laboriously clicking.

Comment: The correct path for the NoClose value would be `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\policies\Explorer` but anyhow, I don't think this answers the question as [it seems](https://admx.help/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.StartMenu::NoClose) this prevent Shutdown altogether, and not just from Alt+F4.

Comment: This is too aggressive; it also hides the shutdown options on the Win-X menu. After activating this, I only was able to shut down the machine by using an administrator console.