# How to disable the Alt+F4 shortcut to signing of in Windows 10

Tags: windows

When I press Alt+F4, the Windows either close the window I am in (which is good) or sign off the Windows if there is no window opened. This last behavior I would like to disable. 
Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it there any way to prevent alt+f4 shutdown in windows](https://superuser.com/questions/718758/is-it-there-any-way-to-prevent-altf4-shutdown-in-windows).  Of course this also disables the ability to perform a shutdown.  You will have to decide if you want the ability to shutdown (which means the shortcut will perform a shutdown) or if you want to prevent the ability to perform a shutdown (which means the shortcut will only close programs).

Comment: When you close the program designated the shell Windows shuts down. This is where the shell program is specified - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon` and `Shell=`

Comment: I tried what @BlueBerry suggested in the other question but I can't find the key he mentioned. Maybe that is not for Windows 10.

Comment: It won't exist by default. You have to create it.